# How to solve problem with compile protobuf in scala project on Windows10?

Tags: scala, grpc, protoc, scalapb

I have simple code with example protobuf on scala

proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";

package grpc.example;

message HelloRequest {
  string msg = 1;
  int32 code = 2;
}


message HelloResponse {
  string msg = 1;
}

service HelloWorld {
  rpc hello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse);
}
```

plugins.sbt in project folder

```
addSbtPlugin("com.thesamet" % "sbt-protoc" % "1.0.0")

libraryDependencies += "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "compilerplugin" % "0.10.10"
```

build.sbt

```
name := "custom-grpc"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.13.4"


lazy val protoExample = (project in file("proto-example"))
  .settings(

    PB.targets in Compile := Seq(
      scalapb.gen() -> (sourceManaged in Compile).value / "scalapb"
    ),
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime" % scalapb.compiler.Version.scalapbVersion % "protobuf"
    ),
    scalaVersion := "2.13.4"
  )


lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(protoExample)
```

When in sbt shell call command *compile* I have error

```
[info] Compiling schema C:\Users\<.....>\IdeaProjects\LearnScala\custom-grpc\proto-example\src\main\protobuf\hello.proto
Error: Could not find or load main class protocbridge.frontend.BridgeApp
--jvm_0_out: protoc-gen-jvm_0: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

What is error ???
I am use Windows10 and jdk 1.8 and then jdk 11.

Comment: The last time a similar issue was reported, the cause was unusual characters in the home directory (looks like you stripped that out in `<.....>` in the post above) - can you try using a directory without special characters? This has been reported in https://github.com/thesamet/sbt-protoc/issues/72

Comment: Thanks but im use path without special characters..

Comment: I opened an issue to track this on https://github.com/thesamet/sbt-protoc/issues/215 - can you try the suggested steps on the ticket and we can continue over github, as I assume at this point we are looking at a bug rather than a usage question.